# Dúvida com GetDate()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma consulta SQL que deveria me trazer apenas os registros cuja data é maior que a data do dia, mais está vindo registros com a data atual. Agradeço!

```
   --não deveria mostrar a data de hoje
 select a.datavencimento  from TB_RECEBIMENTO a   
 left outer join   tb_plano_contas b  on  a.controleplano = b.controleplano               
 left outer join   tb_cliente_fornecedor d   on  a.controlecliente = d.controlecliente    
  where getdate() > a.datavencimento                                                 
     and a.statusregistro   = 'A' 
     and  b.tipododocumento = 'C' 
     and  a.controleempresa = '1' 
     order by a.datavencimento asc
```

Resultado:

```
2015-04-27 00:00:00.000
2015-04-27 00:00:00.000
2015-04-27 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A razão por que isso está a acontecer é que `GetDate()` retorna um *DateTime*, além da data retorna também a parte do `Time` referente às horas, minutos e segundos.

Os dados gravados estão todos com a parte do `Time` a *zero*.
Quando a comparação é feita todas as datas de hoje são menores que getData().

Espero ter me feito compreender.

Comment: Perfeito a sua explicação!

Answer (score 2):

Você deve desconsiderar as horas para fazer essa comparação. Assim:

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Uma dica é criar uma função para isso, para deixar o código mais claro:

```
CREATE FUNCTION truncate_date (@data DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 
(
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @data))
)
END
```

Então sua Query ficaria:

```
select a.datavencimento  from TB_RECEBIMENTO a   
left outer join   tb_plano_contas b  on  a.controleplano = b.controleplano               
left outer join   tb_cliente_fornecedor d   on  a.controlecliente = d.controlecliente    
where dbo.truncate_date(getdate()) > a.datavencimento
-- ou DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) > a.datavencimento
 and a.statusregistro   = 'A' 
 and  b.tipododocumento = 'C' 
 and  a.controleempresa = '1' 
 order by a.datavencimento asc
```

Comment: Essa solução se aplica a qualquer edição do SQL Server. Se estiver usando o SQL Server 2008 ou superior, a solução do bfavaretto também é válida.

Answer (score 1):

Você está tendo esse resultado porque a hora atual (pega pelo `GETDATE()`) está sendo considerada (é um valor do tipo `DATETIME`). Assim, hoje ao meio-dia é maior que hoje à meia-noite (que parece ser o horário de todos os vencimentos), e os vencimentos de hoje atendem à condição da query. Uma das soluções possíveis é converter o retorno do `GETDATE` para o tipo `DATE` (disponível a partir do SQL Server 2008):

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) > a.datavencimento        
-- etc.
```

Comment: Lembrando que o tipo DATE só existe a partir do SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Verdade, complementei a resposta com essa informação.

Comment: Perfeito a sua explicação!